# KeyError at /login u'message'

Tags: python, django, keyerror

```
def loginUser(request):
    if request.method != 'POST':
        return redirect('/')
    attempt = User.objects.validateUser(request.POST)
    if attempt['status'] == True:
        request.session['user_id'] = attempt['user'].id
        return redirect('/books')
    else:
        messages.add_message(request, messages.ERROR, attempt['message'], extra_tags="login")
        return redirect('/')
```

KeyError at /login
u'message'
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/login
Django Version: 1.11
Exception Type: KeyError
Exception Value:
u'message'

Comment: not sure whats going on here... need help!

Comment: it means `attempt` dictionary does not have the key 'message', if it is optional you may try `attemp.get('message', 'default_msg')`

Comment: What is `validateUser`? That seems to be a method you've defined on a custom manager, which returns a dictionary; that dictionary apparently does not contain a "message" key. Note that this is a *very* odd way of doing validation.

Answer (score 1):

It says that the dictionary `attempt` does not have the key `message`. Here you get the dictionary:

```
attempt = User.objects.validateUser(request.POST)
```

At this point inspect the value of `attempt` (print in console, or assert False and deal interactively in browser). If it does not have the value for key `message` you may provide here (validateUser method) or, let it be optional, and change the way you access the value at:

```
messages.add_message(request, messages.ERROR, attempt.get('message', 'default_msg'), extra_tags="login")
```

Note, the changes is from:

```
attempt.['message']
```

to

```
attempt.get('message', 'default_msg')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use these two ways.

```
# either
try:
    message = attempt['message']
except KeyError:
    message = 'default message or your own message'
# or
message = attempt.get('message', 'default message you need to set it yourself')

# after that just use the message variable
messages.add_message(request, messages.ERROR, message, extra_tags="login")
```